# How do I add newlines to a CakePHP script block?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

With CakePHP, it's possible to insert normal JavaScript by putting the following inside a view:

```
$this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false));
echo 'alert("Hello world!");';
$this->Html->scriptEnd();
```

Unfortunately, if you have multiple echo statements, all the text is squashed into 1 long line. Is there any way to split up the lines and insert newlines?

I've already tried adding \n to the end of the echo'd statement to no avail.

I think it's possible to have JS run correctly all in 1 line with proper use of semicolons but it makes for a painful reading and debugging experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using Js->buffer as follows:

```
echo $this->Js->buffer('$(\'<input type="button" id="instaSave" value="Save"/>\')
    .click(function(){ 
        $(this).val("Saving...");

        $(this).parents("form:first").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(responseText, responseCode) {
                $(".food").each(function(fIndex){
                   ...
');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try not putting it in PHP if you dont need to:

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false)); ?>
     alert("Hello world!");
     alert("Hello world!");
<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

Then just use normal js formatting.

Or, you can use [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to echo a newline that isn't within a string literal.

```
<?php
     $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false));
     echo 'alert("Hello world!");' . PHP_EOL;
     echo 'alert("Hello world!");';
     $this->Html->scriptEnd();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understand your question correctly but try to escape your `\n` since php will interpret it as a normal string before your javascript take turn, so for example:

```
$first = "This is first line\\n";
$both  = $first . "This is second line";
```